# Swagger - Get Model to validate my API with 'assertJsonStructure'

Tags: api, swagger

I wrote an API documentation (JSON\YAML) using **Swagger** and now I'd like to get the **Model** example for each RESTful and use It to validate my API output using **PHPUnit** test.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a repo that will allow you to do assertions on your schema with PHP unit. I hope it helps:)

https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions